# Control ngRepeat limit outside the repeat structure

Tags: angularjs

How can I control the `ngRepeat` limit outside of `repeat` structure ?

I tryied archieve this like the code below but, without success.

```
<my-directive-body ng-init="limit = 2">
   <my-directive-actions-group-items>
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-birthday-cake">Today Birthday</my-directive-actions-items>
   </my-directive-actions-group-items>

   <!-- Here I have a repeat -->
   <my-directive-actions-group-items ng-repeat="item in researchs | limitTo: limit">
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-user">{{item.nome}}</my-directive-actions-items>
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-edit"></my-directive-actions-items>
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-trash-o"></my-directive-actions-items>
   </my-directive-actions-group-items>
   <!-- End of Repeat -->   

   <!-- Here I want control the ngRepeat limit -->   
   <my-directive-ctions-group-items>
      <span ng-click="limit = researchs.length">More...</span>
   </my-directive-actions-group-items>
</my-directive-actions-body>
```

**Image Sample**

[image]

Comment: Does `my-directive-body` directive transclude the contents?

Comment: Yes, is just a `div` with transclude, like `<div><ng-transclude /></div>`

Comment: I see no reason why 'limit' wouldn't be in scope - it should be working.

Comment: I got it, I've created a `$scope.limit` in my controller, and change the limitTo to `limitTo: limit`. In `More researchs` I put a `ng-click` and then created a function that just update the `$scope.limit` like `$scope.limit = $scope.researchs.length;`. By the way, I don't know if this is the best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it

**View**

```
<my-directive-body>
   <my-directive-actions-group-items>
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-birthday-cake">Today Birthday</my-directive-actions-items>
   </my-directive-actions-group-items>

   <!-- Here I have a repeat -->
   <my-directive-actions-group-items ng-repeat="item in researchs | limitTo: limit">
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-user">{{item.nome}}</my-directive-actions-items>
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-edit"></my-directive-actions-items>
      <my-directive-actions-items icon="fa-trash-o"></my-directive-actions-items>
   </my-directive-actions-group-items>
   <!-- End of Repeat -->   

   <!-- Here I want control the ngRepeat limit -->   
   <my-directive-ctions-group-items>
      <span ng-click="getAllSearchs()">More...</span>
   </my-directive-actions-group-items>
</my-directive-actions-body>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.limit = 2;
$scope.getAllSearch = function () {
   $scope.limit == $scope.researchs.length ? $scope.limit = 2 : $scope.limit = $scope.researchs.length;            
}
```